# change .txt to .csv in R

Tags: r, string, csv, export-to-csv

I have been able to create a code in R to batch formate all my .txt file to .csv files using

```
setwd("~/Desktop/test/")
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".txt")
for (i in 1:length(filelist)){
    input<-filelist[i]
    output<-paste0(input, ".csv")
    print(paste("Processing the file:", input))
    data = read.delim(input, header = TRUE)   
    setwd("~/Desktop/test/done/")
    write.table(data, file=output, sep=",", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
    setwd("~/Desktop/test/")
}
```

Works great but file still retains the .txt extension in the name
Example origninal file = "sample1.txt" and then the new file says "sample1.txt.csv" The file works as a .csv but the extra ".txt" in the file name annoys me, anyone know how to remove it from name?
thanks

Comment: Your original text files also have extra `.txt` as in `sample1.txt.txt`. So I guess your `input` has `sample1.txt.txt`, and then through code it shows you `sample1.txt.csv` 

You input filenames has extra `.txt` so it appears in output too, as you have said in `output` that `paste0(input,'.csv')`

Comment: Change `output<-paste0(input, ".csv")` to `output<-paste0(strsplit(input, '\\.')[[1]][1], ".csv")` or something along those lines...

Comment: @KarstenW.'s answer below is cleaner :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could delete the unwanted `.txt`:

```
output <- paste0(gsub("\\.txt$", "", input), ".csv")
```

The backslash marks the dot as literal dot (it has other meaning in regular expressions if not marked). The backslash has to be doubled because R tries to escape single backslashes. The dollar sign represents the end of the string, so only ".txt" at the end of the filename gets removed.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much for the code and the explanation works great

Answer (score 1):

```
write.table(filelist,file=paste0("~/Desktop/test/done/",sub(".txt","",filelist[i]),".csv"),row.names=F,colnames=T,quote=F,sep=",")
```

Alternative help:

```
setwd("~/Users/Rio/Documents/Data/")
FILES <- list.files( pattern = ".txt")

for (i in 1:length(FILES)) {
FILE=read.table(file=FILES[i],header=T,sep="\t")
write.table(FILE,file=paste0("~Users/Rio/Documents/Data/",sub(".txt","",FILES[i]),".csv"),row.names=F,quote=F,sep=",")
}
```